# Change type Column with 2 format Python

Tags: python, pandas

**Hello World,**

New in Python, I am trying to convert a column (YEAR) into one format.

The column contains 2 formats:
- yy
- yyyy

Here is an example

```
year
2007
07
1999
2001
99
```

What I have tried is to fill 20 before year column but what about when date is 99.

The desire output will be something like

```
year   new_year
2007   2007
07     2007
1999   1999
2001   2001
99     1999
```

Thanks for anyone helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with format for `YY` - `%y` and `errors='coerce'` and  with [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html), so non format `YY` return missing values replaced by original with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['new_year'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%y', errors='coerce').dt.year
                    .fillna(df['year'])
                    .astype(int))
print (df)
   year  new_year
0  2007      2007
1    07      2007
2  1999      1999
3  2001      2001
4    99      1999
```